# Mpi file not recognized?

Tags: c, ubuntu, mpi

I am trying to run some mpi files on Ubuntu I installed the library using this code

```
sudo apt-get install libcr-dev mpich2 mpich2-doc
```

and tried to run this simple hello world program

```
/* C Example */
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int rank, size;

    MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);      /* starts MPI */
    MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);        /* get current process id */
    MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);        /* get number of processes */
    printf( "Hello world from process %d of %dn", rank, size );
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

The library is well installed yet I can't seem to compile any program 
the hello file is on the desktop

```
Reading state information... Done
libcr-dev is already the newest version.
mpich2 is already the newest version.
mpich2-doc is already the newest version.
```

here is the error I keep getting for any mpi Program I try and compile

```
 gcc: error: mpi_hello.c: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Surely you mean "compile" not "run"? The latter error is a compilation error. What is the command you are using to compile the code?

Comment: Yes Compile ..I used this command 
mpicc mpi_hello.c -o hello

Comment: Also note that I tried to compile it on a different computer and got the same error

Comment: might seem like a stupid question, but are you in the right directory and is the file definitely named `mpi_hello.c`? Bear in mind that on Linux character case in file names does matter, if the actual name of the file is something like `MPI_hello.c` or `Mpi_hello.c`, the compiler is going to puke

Comment: Yes I checked many times the file is on the desktop and named exactly hello.c still got the same error

Comment: Does `ls mpi_hello.c` in a terminal list the file? If it doesn't, compiling is also unlikely to work…

Comment: what do you mean by "is in a terminal list file "?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error messages means the compiler is not able to find the file you want to compile. Since you checked the file name, the most likely explanation is you are not running the command in the directory in which the file resides.

If the file is on your desktop, you should change your current directory to the desktop before running the compilation command, with something like `cd ~/Desktop`.

If the problem lied with your installation of MPI, the error message would looke more like

```
-bash: mpicc: command not found
```